# Convert stream to object with generics

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JSON response from a web service, I want to convert it to a `List<Foo>`.  I know I can do this several ways, but the only way that supports generics that I can see in the JSON.NET documentation is from a `string`.

The response is potentially large, so I don't really want to read it all into memory, then convert it to my object.

I've tried:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (responseStream == null) throw new Exception("ResponseStream is null!!!");

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                // var foos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>()  -- Requires a string
                // var foos = new JsonConverter<List<Foo>>().ReadJson()... -- Non generic
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Can I read it directly from the stream into a `List<Foo>` without having to do this?

Comment: Please check the answer with the more votes. This is what you need,  the method `DeserializeFromStream`. Then you can cast the result to the type you have mentioned, `List<Foo>`.

Comment: @Christos I know I can do that, I wanted to know if there was a method that supported generics.  That answer simply returns an `object`.

Comment: According to this post, there isn't _anymore_ such a method. If you want I can reopen the post and wait for an answer. Please just let me know. Thanks